# How to order_by from specific data

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a database like this

```
order_id | date               | qty
------------------------------------
a        |2018-11-11 10:03:33 |1
b        |2018-11-12 10:03:33 |1
c        |2018-11-11 12:03:33 |1
```

and I have a model like this,

```
public function get_total_sales_per_day($date_from, $date_to)
{    
    $this->db->select('order_id, SUM(qty) as total, date');
    $this->db->from("order");

    $this->db->group_by('date');
    $this->db->order_by('date','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    log_message("debug", $this->db->last_query());
    return $query->result();
}
```

how to use group_by date but only from the year, month and day?

Comment: you can use `$this->db->group_by(DATE('date'));`

Comment: i have do that, i want group by but from year, month and day only like 2018-10-11 not a complete field

Comment: ya thats why `DATE` is used

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by date only like (y-m-d), not apply group by on time

then some change in your code like:

**Some modification in your code**

```
public function get_total_sales_per_day($date_from, $date_to)
{    
    $this->db->select('order_id, SUM(qty) as total, date');
    $this->db->from("order");

    $this->db->group_by(DATE_FORMAT('date', "%y-%y-%d"));
    $this->db->order_by('date','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    log_message("debug", $this->db->last_query());
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape while using [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function

```
/*You have not used arguments (date_from, date_to) 
  anywhere in active record, decide whether you need that, 
*/

public function get_total_sales_per_day($date_from, $date_to)
{    
    $this->db->select('order_id, SUM(qty) as total, date');
    $this->db->from("order");

    /* This is what you need, $escape = FALSE */
    $this->db->group_by('DATE(`date`)',FALSE);

    /* If field exists in select then  
       you can also use : $this->db->order_by('3','asc',FALSE);
       meaning sort by 3rd field
       OR like below  more readable 
    */
    $this->db->order_by('DATE(`date`)','asc',FALSE);

    /* if you wish to order by datetime then you may keep 
         $this->db->order_by('date','asc');
    */ 


    $query = $this->db->get();
    log_message("debug", $this->db->last_query());
    return $query->result();
}
```

**You may read source code here :**

[`public function group_by($by, $escape = NULL)`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L1198)

[`public function order_by($orderby, $direction = '', $escape = NULL)`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L1273)